# FullCalendar - Changing hidden days with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm filtering my calendar, I change the start and end date, status of my events, and other stuffs. I do that with:

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnFiltrar", function() {
    fechaIni = $("#fechaIni").val();
    fechaFin = $("#fechaFin").val();
    cp = $("#txtCP").val();

    var events = {
        url: "./php/xxxxxxxx.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            fechaIni:     fechaIni,
            fechaFin:     fechaFin,
            cp:           cp,
            provincia:    provincia,
            ...
          }
    }

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEventSource", events);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", events);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
});
```

It works fine. But when I want to change the variable hiddenDays dynamically, I can't make it work!
I add to my code this:
(By default this variables are global)

```
var dias = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"];
var ocultarDias = []; // is empty because it shows all days

// inside click button
diasSeleccionados = $("#selDias").val(); // returns array eg: ["1","2","3","4","5"]
ocultarDias = $(dias).not(diasSeleccionados).get(); // compare 2 arrays and get the difference
```

So, with that and the call fullcalendar with the attribute:

```
function llenarCalendario() {
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        lang: 'es',
        firstDay: 1,
        hiddenDays: ocultarDias,
        ...
     });
}
```

I miss something? I want to do this without reload the page, just call again the function or, as the function on click button, refetchEvents or something like that. Is possible?

Comment: So to understand your question. Do you want to load a calendar with all days and then in a later event (button click, ...) you want to hide some specific days?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do that without reload the page. With the help of @todes using 'options' and adding the three lines below that. 
**Very important: the array of hiddenDays must be an array of ints.**

```
var dias = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"];
var ocultarDias = []; // is empty because it shows all days


$(document).ready(function () { 

llenarCalendario();

$("body").on("click", "#btnFiltrar", function() {
    fechaIni = $("#fechaIni").val();
    fechaFin = $("#fechaFin").val();
    cp = $("#txtCP").val();

    var diasSeleccionados = $("#selDias").val(); // select multiple, returns array eg: ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    ocultarDias = $(dias).not(diasSeleccionados).get(); // compare 2 arrays and get the difference
    ocultarDias = ocultarDias.map(Number); // array of strings to int for fullcalendar to work

    var events = {
        url: "./php/xxxxxxxxxx.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            fechaIni:     fechaIni,
            fechaFin:     fechaFin,
            cp:           cp
          }
    }

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('option', {
      hiddenDays: ocultarDias
    });

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEventSource", events);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", events);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
});

});

function llenarCalendario() {
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        lang: 'es',
        firstDay: 1,
        hiddenDays: ocultarDias,
        ...
     });
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer, which posted 'todes'!

Comment: Yes, in fact I wanted to say in your comments below 'by @todes' but it doesn't work. Nevermind, I will edit this answer, don't worry man.

Answer (score 3):

```
var newhiddendays = [0, 6];         // show Mon-Fr (hide Sat/Sun)

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'hiddenDays', newhiddendays);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the calendar and add the events, which you have already have, again with the following method.

```
function reloadCalendar(){
    //Get all events in a array
    var events = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'getEventSources' ); 

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'destroy' ); // Destroy the calendar
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ //Recreate the calendar with the hidden days
        hiddenDays: [ 2, 4 ]
    });

    //With JavaScript
    events.forEach(function(event) { //Restore all events
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', event);
    });

    //With jQuery
    var jEvents =  $.makeArray(events);
    $(jEvents).each(function( i ) {
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events[i]);
    });
}
```

Now you simply can call the method. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: It an awesome idea, but I cant loop events with .forEach, I tried with .each but neither of the two works...

Comment: I've updated my code, now you can choose jquery or javascript. Just simply remove the option, that you don't need.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I can't destroy my calendar because the buttons and options to filter is inside it, at the top of the calendar where are the default buttons.

Comment: Can you update your question with an error log, what doesn't work?

Comment: I make it work! I will answer my own question. It works with method 'option' with array of ints, no strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it with `option`method in order to set new options for your calendar

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/

```
function llenarCalendario() {
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar('option',{
        lang: 'es',
        firstDay: 1,
        hiddenDays: ocultarDias,
        ...
     });
}
```

Comment: It works here [link](https://jsbin.com/xowaxiyabo/edit?html,js,output), are the `firstDay` and `hiddenDays` changed?

Comment: One more question in your function `llenarCalendario` do you access to the `ocultarDias var`?

Comment: I tried the code of the link, but It doesn't work. And yes, in my function I use the variable ocultarDias.

Comment: It works with 'option'! Just I need to convert the array of strings to ints! Thank you!